# How is the Kelvin temperature of a light source or an image is calculated?

Tags: optics, visible-light, thermal-radiation

I searched for it but couldn't find any answer for this.

For a light source is it simply the average of the full spectrum power?

And how do you compute it for an image? How can you tell the difference between a yellow object lighted by a brighter light and a white object lighted by a yellowish light? Or maybe you can accurately compute it in front of a white sheet?

Edit:

I am talking about a lighting Kelvin temperature (for example of a bulb) rather than the actual temperature of the light source.

Comment: [This may help](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-does-one-determine-the-effective-temperature-of-a-star-from-its-spectrum), if you want inferring a temperature of star from it's spectrum. Non trivial of course. Also for stars there's a [Hertzsprung–Russell diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertzsprung%E2%80%93Russell_diagram) where from star spectral class you can infer it's approximate surface temperature.

Comment: A proper answer could be pages, thanks to human vision and white light LEDs, not Planck Law. See Technology Connection on yt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbvVnOxb1AI  and other content from him (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYbdx4I7STg )